# R error : "attempt to select less than one element in get1index"

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R and I'm trying to use the package **ClonEvol**, however the documentation on the github webpage is very limited. So for now I'm using their example code and trying to adapt it to my data called ***ce***.

```
  ce <- data.frame(
  cluster = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7),
  gene = c("geneA","geneB","geneC","geneD","geneA","geneB","geneC","geneD","geneA","geneB","geneC","geneD","geneA","geneB","geneC",
 "geneD","geneA","geneB","geneC","geneD","geneA","geneB","geneC","geneD","geneA","geneB","geneC","geneD"),
  prim.vaf = c(0.5,0,0,0,0.5,0.5,0,0,1,0.5,0,0,1,0.5,0,0.5,0.5,0.5,0,0.5,0.5,0.5,0,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0)
        )

    cluster <- ce$cluster
    gene <- ce$gene
    prim.vaf <- ce$prim.vaf

    x <- ce

    vaf.col.names <- grep('prim.vaf', colnames(x), value=T)
    sample.names <- gsub('prim.vaf', '', vaf.col.names)
    x[, sample.names] <- x[, vaf.col.names]
    vaf.col.names <- sample.names
    sample.groups <- c('P', 'R');
    names(sample.groups) <- vaf.col.names
    x <- x[order(x$cluster),]

    pdf('box.pdf', width = 3, height = 5, useDingbats = FALSE, title='')
    pp <- variant.box.plot(x,
   cluster.col.name = ce$cluster,
   show.cluster.size = FALSE,
   cluster.size.text.color = 'blue',
   vaf.col.names = vaf.col.names,
   vaf.limits = 70,
   sample.title.size = 20,
   violin = FALSE,
   box = FALSE,
   jitter = TRUE,
   jitter.shape = 1,
   jitter.color = clone.colors,
   jitter.size = 3,
   jitter.alpha = 1,
   jitter.center.method = 'median',
   jitter.center.size = 1,
   jitter.center.color = 'darkgray',
   jitter.center.display.value = 'none',
   highlight = 'is.driver',
   highlight.note.col.name = 'gene',
   highlight.note.size = 2,
   highlight.shape =16,
   order.by.total.vaf = FALSE
    )
    dev.off()
```

However, I get the following error :

```
    Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

And if I delete **cluster.col.name=ce$cluster** and **vaf.col.names=vaf.col.names**, the error becomes the following :

```
    Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : attempt to select less than one     
    element in get1index
```

Has someone any idea of what went wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried posting this on github and contacting package developer.

Comment: if you want more people to jump on your question try to give a _minimal_ reproducible example, with a stress on *minimum*

Answer (score 9):

I met this error message today. I know little about the R package in this question, but I think I can show **what the error message means** here. And maybe it is useful for you to find out the problem.

The error occurs when we **use `NULL` as an index** to subset a list.
Here are the expressions invoking this error message:

```
any.list <- list(1, 2, 3)
# If single brackets, no error occurs: 
any.list[NULL]
## list()

# If double brackets, the error occurs: 
any.list[[NULL]]
## Error in any.list[[NULL]] : 
##   attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

The `list` above can be any list, or even a vector.

```
a.vector <- c(1, 2, 3)
a.vector[[NULL]]
## Error in a.vector[[NULL]] : 
##   attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

Here is a similar error message:

```
any.list[[0]]
## Error in any.list[[0]] : 
##   attempt to select less than one element in get1index <real>
```

END