# filter plot_ly chart by ID using manipulateWidget in R

Tags: r, shiny, widget, rstudio, r-plotly

First time asking a question on here so let me know if I ask in the correct manner.

I am trying to filter a plot_ly chart by Name using manipulateWidget in R but receive the following error message:

> Warning: Error in : All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
>   * Column `color` is NULL   113:

Data structure:

```
Name                 Date            Value
lastName, firstName1 2020-03-19      96.5
lastName, firstName1 2020-03-17      96.0
lastName, firstName2 2020-03-19      87.2
lastName, firstName2 2020-03-17      85.3
lastName, firstName3 2020-03-19      69.1
lastName, firstName3 2020-03-17      70.2
```

My code is as follows:

```
plotVar <- function(xvar, yvar, name) {

  plot_ly(x = ~data[[xvar]], y = ~data[[yvar]], color = ~data[[name]], type = "bar") %>% 
    layout(xaxis = list(title = xvar), yaxis = list(title = yvar))
}

plotVar("Date", "Value", "Name")

varNames <- names(data)[2:3]

manipulateWidget(
  plotVar(xvar, yvar, name),
  xvar = mwSelect(varNames, value = "Date"),
  yvar = mwSelect(varNames, value = "Value"),
  name = mwSelect(choices = data$Name)
)
```

The last line `(name = mwSelect(choices = data$Name))` of my code seems to we where the issue is.

Could any please help? It would be greatly appreciated :)
Please note, I do not come from a computer science background.

Kind Regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter `data` using Name, we need to pass it as an argument, at the same time `plot_ly` needs `color` as a column name in the provided `data`. Here a modified version of your function.

```
plotVar <- function(data_var, xvar, yvar, name, name_choice) {
  if(name_choice=="all"){
    data_var = data_var
    plot_ly(x = ~data_var[[xvar]], y = ~data_var[[yvar]], color = ~data_var[[name]], type = "bar") %>% 
      layout(xaxis = list(title = xvar), yaxis = list(title = yvar))

  } else {
    data_var = data_var[data_var$Name==name_choice,]
    plot_ly(x = ~data_var[[xvar]], y = ~data_var[[yvar]], type = "bar") %>% 
      layout(xaxis = list(title = xvar), yaxis = list(title = yvar))
  }
}

plotVar(data_var = data, "Date", "Value", "Name", name_choice = "all")

varNames <- names(data)

manipulateWidget(
  plotVar(data, xvar, yvar, name, name_choice),
  xvar = mwSelect(varNames, value = "Date"),
  yvar = mwSelect(varNames, value = "Value"),
  name = mwSelect(varNames, value = "Name"), 
  name_choice = mwSelect(choices = c("all", unique(data$Name)))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I run the last section (from manipulateWidget...), I now get the following error: Error in .subset2: attempt to select less than one element in get1index

Any ideas?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949923/r-error-attempt-to-select-less-than-one-element-in-get1index. Please note that `varNames` is equal to  `names(data)` not `names(data)[2:3]`